# CommandLindParser do not work with negative arguments (double)

Tags: c++, opencv, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-line-parser

To parse the command line arguments with OpenCV (C++) I have defined the keyString like that:

```
const String keyStrings = "{@filepath | lena.jpg | input image}"
        "{@commandCode | color2BW | command code}"
        "{@alpha | 1.0 | alpha}"
        "{@beta | 1.0 | beta}";
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keyStrings);
```

When I get the alpha, beta like this:

```
double alpha = parser.get<double>("@alpha");
double beta = parser.get<double>("@beta");
```

If someone pass the alpha or beta values as a negative number, alpha, beta will received 1.0 as its values. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Probably because `'-'` is just as commonly used to prefix command switches as `'/'` is. The parser probably doesn't know to parse those parameters as numbers

Answer (score 0):

i'd think, this is a bug (which should be [reported](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/new/choose))

however you can work around it by using *named* arguments instead of *positional* (prefixed with `@`) ones, like:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const String keyStrings =
            "{alpha | 1.0 | alpha}" // no @
            "{beta | 1.0 | beta}";
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keyStrings);

    double alpha = parser.get<double>("alpha"); // no @
    double beta = parser.get<double>("beta");
    cout << alpha << " " << beta << endl;
}
```

and use it like:

```
./demo --alpha=3 --beta=-2
```